# Android app selecting photo from gallery not displaying

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am making an android app and I have a button that when the user clicks it will do a popup asking the user if they would like to take photo, choose from library, or cancel.  When the user takes a new photo it will replace the place holder image in the activity with the image that was just taken.  Whenever the user tries to choose from the library the image is not being displayed and the place holder image is disappearing.  Below is the part of the code that deals with clicking the photo button, and below it is the attributes assigned to the button and image.

```
/** Called when the user clicks the photo button */
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewDogActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}


private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
    int scale = 1;
    while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
            && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

This is the attributes for the button and image.

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Photo"
    android:id="@+id/selectImgButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/BreededitText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/BreededitText"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#2c7134"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textColor="#f3ca83"
    android:onClick="choosePicture"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageText"
    android:src="@drawable/ddlogo"
    android:layout_above="@+id/NewSubmitButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/selectImgButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/selectImgButton" />
```

Comment: Delete your entire `onSelectFromGalleryResult()` implementation and have it delegate the work to [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).

Comment: Your code looks fine . May be there is OOM error. Please check logs.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I have been emailing the apk to myself and opening it on my phone.  Is there a way to see the error that my phone may be receiving?

Comment: Use logcat to check the app logs.